How Does Java process exits gracefully by shutting kafka consumers and producers during pod deletion in Kubernetes
When the kubectl pod delete command is issued, it isn't waiting for the shutdown hook in a Java Kafka consumer and producer application to complete processing any unprocessed events. What steps need to be taken to ensure the application gracefully exits after the kubectl pod delete command is fired?
Tried Prestop lifecycle hook.
Prestop:
kill -SIGTERM pid ; sleep 5min
Added kill as well as sleep to reduce the event  loss.
But this is not working as expected. Please suggest a better way of handling this.

Simply scale down your Kafka first, then delete it. Kafka usually runs in a stateful set and you are basically killing a pod with kubectl delete - not a good combination. You could set terminationGracePeriodSeconds in the pod spec, but that is... tricky: Will your pod really be done after that time? Also, you should ask yourself a question: Why are you forcefully killing pods?
